# why the file's Date Modified attribute changed,But I'm sure the file is not modified at all

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, filesystems, ext4

I have a [little script](https://raw.github.com/michalliu/CubieDebian/master/utilities/createDiectoryListing.sh) to create a directory listing

You can use it like

`./createDiectoryListing.sh SOME_DIRECTORY`

It will create a `index.html` show the list of the file, [Here is an example](http://cubieplayer.github.io/Cubian/dist/)

But i found sometime the file's date modified attribute changed to the time i ran the script.

In my script, i just use `md5sum` to caculate the hash of the file, I never change the content.

It's really annoying, all the file has the same modified date,after i ran the script

I don't know why, anyone can help me out thanks.

Comment: If it really is a "little script", you should post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I figured it out. the reason is i use git to manage the file. when switch between branches, the date attribute is changed.